# Tensorflow: Probability of an outcome in multinomial try

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, distribution

I'm doing a multinomial try - I have a vector of probabilities `p=[p1, p2, p3]` and a vector of observed outcomes `n=[n1, n2, n3]`.

How does one find the probability of such an event using TensorFlow? I would like to have a solution working for matrices as well (i.e. I have a tensor such that each row represents probabilities and a tensor such that each row represents outcomes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tf.distributions.Multinomial`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distributions/Multinomial):

```
import tensorflow as tf

probs = tf.constant([.2, .4, .6], tf.float32)
counts = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], tf.float32)
total_count = tf.reduce_sum(counts)
multinomial = tf.distributions.Multinomial(total_count, probs=probs)
prob_counts = multinomial.prob(counts)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(prob_counts))
```

Output:

```
0.13888888
```

You can also operate with multiple distributions at once like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

probs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
counts = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
total_counts = tf.reduce_sum(counts, axis=1)
multinomial = tf.distributions.Multinomial(total_counts, probs=probs)
prob_counts = multinomial.prob(counts)
```

In this case each row of `probs` would be a probability distribution, each row of `counts` a distribution sample and each element of `prob_counts` the probability of each sample.